# Free, Complete Soccer Database?

Tags: data-request

I'm making an application in C # that currently uses the [following](http://football-data.org).
They are very basic and do not even have tables form, wide, half-time and in addition there are very few championships.
I also tried to contact the admin of the site 5 times but she never answered.
I found these API: https://statsfc.com/ but are not free, I would like to know if there is a service that currently offers the most comprehensive database free kick.

Comment: What fields and relations do you want from a database?

Comment: I want a database of soccer rich of data, that's what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this might be a decent resource?  Found after googling for "fifa database opendata": https://openfootball.github.io/